# Adding custom message to Zend Framework 2 Callback Validator

Tags: validation, callback, zend-framework2, message

I would like to add a custom error message to my Callback Validator below ("Zip Code is required" for example), how would I go about doing this?

```
   $zip = new \Zend\InputFilter\Input('zip');
        $zip->setRequired(false);
        $zip->getValidatorChain()
        ->attach(new \Zend\Validator\Callback(function ($value, $context) {
            if($context['location_type_id'] == \Application\Model\ProjectModel::$LOCATION_TYPE_ID_AT_AN_ADDRESS)
            {
                return (isset($value)&&($value!= NULL))? $value: false;
            }
            return true;
        }));
```

If you need more information, let me know and I will update.
Thanks for your help!

Abor

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it that way :

```
$callback = new \Zend\Validator\Callback(function ($value) {
        // Your validation logic
    }
);
$callback->setMessage('Zip Code is required');

$zip = new \Zend\InputFilter\Input('zip');
$zip->setRequired(false);
$zip->getValidatorChain()->attach($callback);
```

Comment: Perfect jchampion, I will update the question with the final solution.

Answer (score 10):

Just to throw in my two cents, a custom message can also be set via configuration. I often use this when using a factory type approach like so:

```
'name' => array(
    ...
    'validators' => array(
        new \Zend\Validator\Callback(
            array(
                'messages' => array(\Zend\Validator\Callback::INVALID_VALUE => '%value% can only be Foo'),
                'callback' => function($value){
                    return $value == 'Foo';
                }))
    )
),
```

This produces a message like "Bar can only be Foo".

Look closely at the `\Zend\Validator\Callback::INVALID_VALUE` key, this is a constant defined in \Zend\Validator\Callback:

```
const INVALID_VALUE = 'callbackValue';
```

Which is used in that class to set the messages used by the validator:

```
protected $messageTemplates = array(
    self::INVALID_VALUE    => "The input is not valid",
    self::INVALID_CALLBACK => "An exception has been raised within the callback",
);
```

Which means you can safely use `\Zend\Validator\Callback::INVALID_VALUE => 'Custom message'`

I'm not sure whether this breaks a coding principle, somebody please correct me if it does.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to jchampion for his help.

```
        $zip = new \Zend\InputFilter\Input('zip');
        $zip->setRequired(false);            
        $callback = new \Zend\Validator\Callback(function ($value, $context) {
            if($context['location_type_id'] == \Application\Model\ProjectModel::$LOCATION_TYPE_ID_AT_AN_ADDRESS)
            {
                return (isset($value)&&($value!= NULL))? true: false;
            }
            return true;
        });
        $callback->setMessage('Zip Code is required');
        $zip->getValidatorChain()->attach(new \Zend\Validator\NotEmpty(\Zend\Validator\NotEmpty::NULL));
        $zip->getValidatorChain()->attach($callback);
```